# Java UnsatisfiedLinkError Mac OSX

Tags: java, macos, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I have a Java app that works fine with Java 1.6 on OSX. However once you update to java latest version (1.7) it stops working and gives out the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Users/lvarela/Library/Application Support/Oracle/Java/Deployment/cache/6.0/41/3937a929-7be268b9-n/libpteidlibJava_Wrapper.dylib: dlopen(/Users/lvarela/Library/Application Support/Oracle/Java/Deployment/cache/6.0/41/3937a929-7be268b9-n/libpteidlibJava_Wrapper.dylib, 1): Library not loaded: @loader_path/libpteidcommon.3.5.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/lvarela/Library/Application Support/Oracle/Java/Deployment/cache/6.0/41/3937a929-7be268b9-n/libpteidlibJava_Wrapper.dylib
  Reason: image not found
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1939)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1864)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1838)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:845)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)
    at pt.gov.cartaodecidadao.applet.nativelibs.LibLoader.loadLibraryNG(LibLoader.java:55)
    at pt.gov.cartaodecidadao.applet.util.UtilApplet.init(UtilApplet.java:110)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.init(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I did not developed this application and I'm quite new to Java. So I'm completely in the dark about what may be causing this problem. It's an online app however I have it running locally using a jetty server.

Can any of you help me figure this out?